# How to create a probability for exit obstruction (targetline) and make pedestrians choose alternative exits using anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am currently working on a floor fire evacuation of a building using pedestrians that works with a click of a button. I would like to create a probability (example 0.2 for 1 exit obstruction, <0.2 for 2 and so on) when the button is clicked that a fire would obstruct 1, 2, all or none of the 3 exits (targetline) and make pedestrians move to an alternative closest exit. How can I do that with anylogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Exit blocking (with certain probability)

You can use the built in [probability distributions](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fstochastic%2FProbability+Distributions.html) in AnyLogic to get one of your options with a required probability. In your case you could use the [uniform distribution](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2Funiform.html) for each exit to determine if it is obstructed or not. Run this for example at model startup. As we cannot really 'obstruct' a targetLine, we go the other way round: we collect those who are not obstructed and only allow those to be choosen as destinations. To do so we save each available exit in a Collection *availableExits*. Later when deciding which exit to take, we will tell the decision function to only consider those in the list. Put this in the *On Startup* section of your *Main* properties:

```java
if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine1);
}
if(uniform(0,1)<0.6){ // 40% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine2);
}
if(uniform(0,1)<0.9){ // 10% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine3);
}
```

Define the Collection *availableExits* like this:

[image: Collection]

## Process Flow for Evacuation

For the evacuation, you can prepare a separate process flow that the Agents enter when the evacuation is trigered. This flow could be attached to the main process flow over the ccl/evacuation ports of the pedestrian library blocks.

[image: Process]

In the separate evacuation process flow, put a moveTo block, in which the destination is beeing given by a function.

[image: GoTo Block]

## Nearest available exit

This function will iterate through all exits in your Collection *availableExits* and choose the closest one. Input parameter is of type *Pedestrian* and named *ped*, output parameter is of type *TargetLine*.

[image: Function Head]

```java
if(availableExits.size()<1){
    error("No exit is available");
    return null;
}

double currentDistance = ped.getPosition().distance2D(new Point(availableExits.get(0).getX(),availableExits.get(0).getY());
double minDistance = currentDistance;
TargetLine closestExit = availableExits.get(0);

for(int i=1;i<availableExits.size();i++){
    currentDistance= ped.getPosition().distance2D(new Point(availableExits.get(i).getX(),availableExits.get(i).getY());
    if(currentDistance<minDistance){
        minDistance = currentDistance;
        closestExit = availableExits.get(i);
    }
}

return closestExit;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just started learning this software and am not very familiar with java coding. So where do I add my uniform distribution code? I have written the code as uniform(0.2)

Comment: I've managed to create a collection but don't know how to call it as function in the moveTo block.

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanation and screenshots.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error in the function body stating that, "The method distance2D(Point) in the type Point is not applicable for the arguments (TargetLine)". 
Can I know what this means?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The method distance2D only takes Point as an argument, not a TargetLine. You can exchange the expression:

ped.getPosition().distance2D(availableExits.get(0)) with: 
ped.getPosition().distance2D( new Point(availableExits.get(0).getX(),availableExits.get(0).getY() );

and analog to that:

ped.getPosition().distance2D(availableExits.get(i)) with:
ped.getPosition().distance2D( new Point(availableExits.get(i).getX(),availableExits.get(i).getY() );

Comment: I followed everything using your model that you have sent me before and got it working. But in my simulation model it says 3 things:
1. In Function "Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to double"
2. In PedGoTo "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to TargetLine"
3. In Function "Type mismatch: cannot convert from TargetLine to double."

Comment: Oh sorry I made a blunder, I got it working but I have one final question sir. How does the probability for obstruction work. Does it change each time I run the simulation?

Comment: You can not really "block" an entry line. So what I am doing in the solution is just not add it to the list of potential exits (availableExits), so that it never gets choosen by the moveTo as a target and therefore no Agent uses this exit (= same as if obstructed). Run your model several times and have a look at the availableExits Collection -> it should sometimes contain 1, sometimes 2 and sometimes 3 exits. The exits not present in the Collection are the "obstructed" exits.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: Hi Mr. Florian, after running the model several times it doesn't really change the exits being available unless I manually type in different probability values each time. Is there a way to fix this issues? I tried creating a different if else function but is unable to do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the model properties, in the tab randomness, you can specify if you want the same or a different seed value for all probabilistic functions. If you do not want the reproducible result like now, choose that a different seed is used for each run.